# Get WooCommerce subtotal AFTER coupons

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm using this code:

WC()->cart->subtotal;

to check how much money the customer has to spend until she gets free shipping. The free shipping amount considers coupon codes though so I need to subtract any discount from WC()->cart->subtotal; before displaying the total amount. Any idea?

I've tried to do something like this:

```
$current = WC()->cart->subtotal - WC()->cart->discounts;
```

But it isn't doing anything.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want display the total amount (subtotal - discount) you can write this :

```
WC()->cart->total;
```

So, you can do this for example :

```
  $amount_for_free_shipping= 49;
  $cart = round(WC()->cart->total,2);
  $remaining = $amount_for_free_shipping - $cart;
```

Comment: To anyone who finds this just note that cart-> total also will include shipping cost and fees, so this is not the same as just having a subtotal minus discount, because subtotal does not include shipping cost or fees

Comment: WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total(); will give you the cart after discounts, but wont include shipping, taxes or fees.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tomer ... This is how free shipping calculation should actually work ... after discounts but not include shipping, taxes, or fees ... `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();`

Here is how I calculate and show the Free Shipping message on the cart page:

```
//≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡
// free shipping calculation message
//≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping', 'ecos_woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping', 20 );
function ecos_woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping() {
    $amount_for_free_shipping = 49;

    // cart subtotal before discounts
    // $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->get_displayed_subtotal(); // html display
    // $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
    // $cart_subtotal_formatted = number_format((float)$cart_subtotal, 2, '.', ',');

    // cart subtotal after discounts, but won't include shipping, taxes or fees
    $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
    $cart_subtotal_formatted = number_format((float)$cart_subtotal, 2, '.', ',');

    if( $amount_for_free_shipping > $cart_subtotal ) {
        $remaining_free_shipping = $amount_for_free_shipping - $cart_subtotal;
        $remaining_free_shipping = number_format((float)$remaining_free_shipping, 2, '.', '');
        $remaining_free_shipping_percent = round(($remaining_free_shipping / $amount_for_free_shipping) * 100);
        $remaining_free_shipping_percent = number_format((float)$remaining_free_shipping_percent, 2, '.', '');
    }
    else {
        $remaining_free_shipping = 0;
        $remaining_free_shipping_percent = 0;
    }
    if($remaining_free_shipping > 0) {
        $_freeShippingText = 'Want <strong>FREE SHIPPING</strong>?<br />Just add <strong>$<span id="ecos-modal-cart-free-shipping-amount-remaining">' . $remaining_free_shipping . '</span></strong> to your order';
    }
    else {
        $_freeShippingText = 'You get <strong>FREE SHIPPING</strong> !';
    }

    echo '<tr class="ecos-free-shipping-calculator">
    <td colspan="2">'.$_freeShippingText.'</td></tr>';
}
```